# External file upload including source url as file name?

Tags: php, wordpress, rename

Currently I am using `wp_upload_bits` to upload images externally to my website and its working now, however the images are maintaining our source URL as the file name.

```
$post['image'] = $_POST['image'];
$upload = wp_upload_bits($_POST['image'], null, file_get_contents($_POST['image']));
$filename = $upload['file'];
$wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($filename, null );
$attachment = array(
    'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
    'post_title' => 'cover',
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => 'inherit'
);
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename, $post_id );
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $hello );
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_id );
```

The above code returns something which looks similar to this within our WordPress site.

[image]

How can I solve this, so that I can set my file name via a string?

Answer (score 1):

Change: `$filename = $upload['file'];`

To: `$filename = basename($upload['file']);`

Then it will be stored as: `llYtuLT-10.jpg`

Comment: sidenote, you might want to check that its safe from uploading PHP files, `file_get_contents($_POST['image'])` looks dangerous..

Comment: This does not work, have been tinkering with it for 10 minutes now with no luck, the image doesn't display at all when I change it to this.